# How to filter UNIX stdout by numerical constraints?

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, filter

I want to take a stdout stream and filter it to only save values greater than 100 without using `awk`. I have a bunch of other unix commands piped together, which results in a stdout stream of various numbers. I want to pass any number greater than 99 into a file. I image something like this:

`several commands | unix-tool 100 > stdout_that_is_>99`

It seems like this should be trivial and that I am missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Is it >99 or >100, >100 is trickier...

Comment: Here it is >99, but ideally I want a solution that filters by any given constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use grep with a regex to match any 3+ digit number, eg:

```
command | grep '[1-9][0-9]\{2\}' >"stdout_that_is_>99"
```

This would be easily adaptable to work at any order of magnitude.

Comment: Smart answer, i like its flexibility

Answer (score 1):

```
gefilt() {
    while read num; do
        if (( $num+0 >= $1 )); then
            echo $num
        fi
    done
}

several commands | gefilt 100
```